# MySQL group by last entry

Tags: mysql

My table payment_status have these fields:

- id
- payment_id
- status
- created
- created_by

Many entries could have the same payment_id... So, I want to get the last status for one payment_id...

I have this request that work but take too much time to load... I would like to have an optimize version to group by payment_id and take the last status.

```
SELECT pstatus.*
FROM `payment_status` AS pstatus
WHERE pstatus.id = (
   SELECT id
   FROM `payment_status`
   WHERE pstatus.status = '200'
   ORDER BY created DESC
   LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY pstatus.payment_id
ORDER BY pstatus.payment_id DESC
```

Comment: So do you want to get the last status _for one payment ID_ as you said in the question, or _for all payments_ as you seem to be doing in the query? Actually your inner query is wrong, and will sort over either _none_ or _all_ payment rows, depending on whether external query's `pstatus.status` is `'200'`, and not only over those that have a matching `payment_id`.

Comment: You got quite a few good suggestions down there.

Comment: please rate & accept the answer that works for you.

Comment: @Devart seems to have the right solution... Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM payment_status t1
  JOIN (SELECT payment_id, MAX(created) max_created
        FROM payment_status
        GROUP BY payment_id
        ) t2
    ON t1.payment_id = t2.payment_id AND t1.created = t2.max_created;
```

...then add WHERE conditions you need.

Comment: Exactly what I needed... Thanks a lot! 0.0025 second to load this query :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM payment_status p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MAX(created) MaxCreated
    FROM payment_status 
    WHERE status = '200'
    GROUP BY id
) p2 ON p1.id = p2.id AND p1.created = p2.MaxCreated
ORDER BY p1.payment_id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this query load all statuses for each group and not only the more recent one.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
SELECT *
FROM  payment_status
WHERE status = '200'    
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This load only the last status of all statuses :-)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't yo ujust be able to do this?:

(assuming that created is the timestamp, so "last" = "most recent")

```
SELECT pstatus.*
FROM `payment_status` AS pstatus
GROUP BY pstatus.payment_id, pstatus.status
ORDER BY pstatus.payment_id DESC, pstatus.created DESC
```

each row returns should have the payment_id with the most recent status.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this query load all statuses for each group and not only the more recent one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using MySQL database.

Here I have a solution is fast and readable:

```
select 
    substring_index(
        group_concat(status order by created desc)
        , ',', 1
    ) as status_latest 
from payment_status 
group by payment_id
```

I'm quite sure it's fast than others SQL statement, 
You may try it.